# Jquery strips line breaks from asp:labels

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an asp:label that looks like this in a modal on my page:

```
  <asp:Label ID="lblAddClientMessage" ForeColor="Red" CssClass="addClientMessage" Text="This is first line<br />This is second line<br /> This is third line" runat="server" />
```

When the modal is displayed, it shows correctly with 3 lines.

```
This is first line
This is second line
This is third line
```

As you can see, the line breaks are not displaying on the screen because it is interpreted as a line break.

I have a button that is activated when the button is pressed.  But when I change the text, the line break is just handled as text and is displayed on the screen.  I have also tried it as "\n" and "&ltbr /&gt" and get the same result where the line break is displayed instead of interpreted.

```
        $("#<%=btnAddClient.ClientID%>").click(function (e) {
           $(".addClientMessage").text("THis is a test1<br/>This is test2");
           e.preventDefault();
           return;
```

This is displayed as:

```
  THis is a test1<br/>This is test2
```

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `\n` instead of `<br/>` like `$(".addClientMessage").text("THis is a test1\nThis is test2").wrap("<pre />")` or with css `.addClientMessage {white-space: pre-wrap}`

Comment: I did that but it did the same thing.  One line with \n showing on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Use `html()` method of jQuery.

```
$("#<%=btnAddClient.ClientID%>").click(function (e) {
   $(".addClientMessage").html("THis is a test1<br/>This is test2");
   e.preventDefault();
   return;
});
```

Ref : https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_html.asp

Comment: That was it.  I guess I could also have used innerhtml as well.